# AVR inline assembly: output variable changes without instruction to change it

Tags: c++, avr, inline-assembly, avr-gcc

I am trying to write some code in inline assembly for ATmega328P
I found that my output variable changes not in way i expected. So i reduced original code to this:

```
uint8_t a=0;
__asm__ (
        "nop " "\n\t"
        :"=&r" (a)
        : 
        );
```

I am expecting that value of **a** will remain same, but depending of where in my programm i put this code value of **a** sometimes changes to something else.
I am don't understanding why this happens. Will be glad if someone will explain to me what i am missing.

Comment: Maybe looking at the generated assembly code by gcc will provide some hints

Comment: @dim I am new to this. Don't know how :) I am using Microsoft Visual studio with vMicro plagin (Arduino)

Comment: Ok, I never used this plugin, but I'm using Visual Studio regularily for PC development, so maybe it's the same: you can have the disassembly while you're debugging (I suggest putting a breakpoint just before your piece of code) from the menu Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly (or something like that, mine is in French)

Comment: @dim I will try. THank you

Comment: Since you only list `a` as an output, the existing value (a=0) is meaningless, since it is never used.  If you are enabling optimizations, the assignment can be discarded by gcc.  Try using `+&r`.  Other alternatives might be appropriate depending on what the original code looks like.